# Deleting files except if the name contains a substring

Tags: find, filenames, rm

I am using following command for deleting files in a folder. But my command is deleting everything.

```
ionice -c 3 find . -type f -print -delete
```

I don't want to delete a file if have a `_y` suffix.

So, my folder view:

```
123a.jpg -> Should delete
4567.jpg -> Should delete
7644_y.png -> Should not delete
12234_y.jpeg -> Should not delete
5753.jpg -> Should delete
```

How should be the my command for achive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your examples, you want to exclude files whose name contains a `_y` *substring*.

```
find . -type f ! -name '*_y*' -print -delete
```

(With `ionice -c 3` in front if you want, that's independent of what you do with `find`.)

If you wanted to keep files only if `_y` is at the end of the base name (so `12234_y_.jpeg` would be deleted), you could use

```
find . -type f ! -name '*_y.*' -print -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `find` specifically to recurse down subdirectories, then this answer does not apply. If, however, you are only deleting files in the current directory, a bash-specific option is:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -v !(*_y.*)
```

This has the additional limitation of attempting to delete non-files (directories) that match the pattern.